# Problem with image overlaying the navigation bar

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have this problem with the image. I want the nav bar buttons to be over the image but the navbar is covering up the image.

Here is how it is:

[image]

for the background I have

```
img[alt="background"]{
border: none;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 60rem;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

and for the navbar:

```
.navbar{
background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: 10rem;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Do you mean you want your navbar to be `background-color: transparent;` ?

Comment: I didn't realize that ‍♂️

Comment: Thank you that worked

Comment: if DaMaGeX answer worked then please click on the tick (it should then turn green) where you asked your question. Thank you.

Comment: He made a comment there is no tick to click on